# xlwings Calling python from VBA

Tags: python, vba, excel, winapi, xlwings

This is the error I receive after attempting to call a python script from within Excel VBA [http://docs.xlwings.org/quickstart.html]

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named mymodule

Press Ctrl+C to copy this message to the clipboard.
```

Where do I save down the module.py file which contains:

```
import numpy as np
from xlwings import Workbook, Range
def rand_numbers():
    """ produces standard normally distributed random numbers with shape (n,n)"""
    wb = Workbook.caller()  # Creates a reference to the calling Excel file
    n = Range('Sheet1', 'B1').value  # Write desired dimensions into Cell B1
    rand_num = np.random.randn(n, n)
    Range('Sheet1', 'C3').value = rand_num
```

I have imported the `xlwings.bas` as a module into the Visual Basic editor, I have python 2.7.8 on anaconda 2.1.0

```
$ which python
/c/ana/python

$ pip show xlwings
---
Name: xlwings
Version: 0.2.2
Location: c:\ana\lib\site-packages
Requires:
```

I am assuming the xlwings.bas file is linked to my `pythonpath` but how does the sub procedure know how to call the module.py file and/or how does the sub procedure know where the module.py file is located?

```
Sub RandomNumbers()
RunPython ("import mymodule; mymodule.rand_numbers()")
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, the xlwings VBA module expects the Python file in the same directory as the Excel file. This is the `PYTHONPATH` setting that can be changed in the xlwings VBA module.